# Dominoes With Letters

Tags: word, english, letters, dominoes

I have a set with 26 special domino stones. Every stone carries a lower case Latin alphabet letter and an upper case Latin alphabet letter:

```
  a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
  F M C Z P A Q T S K J U B Y O E G W I H L X R V N D
```

I know an English word of ten (not necessarily distinct) letters that I can spell with these stones on the table. If I arrange ten domino stones from left to right so that their lower case letters spell my word, then the upper case letters also spell my word but *backwards*. What is this word?

Comment: Well, just tried brute forcing with every commonly available word. Assuming all letters have to be distinct, you're using an extremely obscure English word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word is

> PILOTHOUSE

Found by searching a list of ten letter words on [this site.](http://www.bestwordlist.com/10letterwords.txt)

Comment: I thought that the letters had to be different, as in non-repeating EDIT: Apparently distinct does not mean distinct anymore.

Comment: Also disappointed by the "distinct" letters not actually being distinct. But the comment about palindromes is not correct; if, for instance, the word starts with a P, it must end with an E.

Comment: You're right! Fixed.

Comment: I am disapointed, I was looking for a word without o and c because of the disctint hint :(

Comment: @SGR Not really, e.g. you could make the word numbly, which has only distinct letters. The fact is just that no 10-letter example exists.